# Count SQL results depending on two rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Here an example of my SQL structure:

```
magazines
     magazines.id
     magazines.templateId
     magazines.userId
```

I would like to count the number of times a user have used a specific template id.

Considering 3 templates id : 100, 101 and 102 and considering 5 users (10, 20, 30, 40, 50). here is an example of the SQL datas:

```
magazines
     1, 100, 10
     2, 100, 20
     3, 100, 30
```

Here, 3 differents users have the template #100. But the result of the query should be [100 = 1] because it's different users. On the other hand, if I have :

```
magazines
     1, 100, 10
     2, 100, 10
```

I should have templateId [100 = 2].

I tried multiple queries with GROUP BY and UNIQUE, by results are completely wrong. If someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the maximum number of times that a user uses a template:

```
select templateid, userid, count(*)
from magazines m
where temploateid = X
group by templateid, userid
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

EDIT:

You can get what you want by aggregating two times:

```
select templateid, cnt, count(*) as numUsers
from (select templateid, userid, count(*) as cnt
      from magazines m
      where temploateid = X
      group by templateid, userid
     ) tu
group by templateid, cnt
order by templateid, cnt;
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's a good track. In fact I need the count of usage for my templates. Template #1, used once = X users, used twice = X users, etc to 20. Is it possible to update the query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the amount of times each user has used a particular template:

```
SELECT
  templateId,
  userId,
  COUNT(id) as cnt
FROM
  Magazines GROUP BY templateId, userId
```

If your table had the following data:

```
  (1, 100, 10),
  (2, 100, 10),
  (3, 100, 20),
  (4, 100, 30)
```

Then you result set would be:

```
templateId  userId  cnt
100         10      2
100         20      1
100         30      1
```